# How to convert strings to lower case in GO?

Tags: go, word-count

I am new to the language GO and working on an assignment where i should write a code that return the word frequencies of the text. However I know that the words 'Hello', 'HELLO' and 'hello' are all counted as 'hello', so I need to convert all strings to lower case.

I know that I should use strings.ToLower(), however I dont know where I should Included that in the class. Can someone please help me?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const DataFile = "loremipsum.txt"

// Return the word frequencies of the text argument.
func WordCount(text string) map[string]int {
    fregs := make(map[string]int)
    words := strings.Fields(text)
    for _, word := range words {
        fregs[word] += 1
    }
    return fregs
}

// Benchmark how long it takes to count word frequencies in text numRuns times.
//
// Return the total time elapsed.
func benchmark(text string, numRuns int) int64 {
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < numRuns; i++ {
        WordCount(text)
    }
    runtimeMillis := time.Since(start).Nanoseconds() / 1e6

    return runtimeMillis
}

// Print the results of a benchmark
func printResults(runtimeMillis int64, numRuns int) {
    fmt.Printf("amount of runs: %d\n", numRuns)
    fmt.Printf("total time: %d ms\n", runtimeMillis)
    average := float64(runtimeMillis) / float64(numRuns)
    fmt.Printf("average time/run: %.2f ms\n", average)
}

func main() {
    // read in DataFile as a string called data
    data, err:= ioutil.ReadFile("loremipsum.txt")
      if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Convert []byte to string and print to screen

    text := string(data)
    fmt.Println(text)
    

    fmt.Printf("%#v",WordCount(string(data)))

    numRuns := 100
    runtimeMillis := benchmark(string(data), numRuns)
    printResults(runtimeMillis, numRuns)
}
```

Comment: there's no classes in Go. you just call `strings.ToLower()` wherever it makes sense in your program flow. Probably here `fregs[string.ToLower(word)] += 1`

Comment: @blackgreen Thank you. When i run it i get  a:822 a.:110 . However I want both of these to be included as just a. How can I take away the period. I have tried with strings.replaceall but it did not work. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You should convert words to lowercase when you are using them as map key

```
for _, word := range words {
        fregs[strings.ToLower(word)] += 1
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! However Now, when a run it I get [a:822 a.:110  I want all a in the same. How do i a change the code so that a and a. is the same?

Answer (score 0):

to remove all non-word characters you could use a regular expression:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str1 := "This is some text! I want to count each word. Is it cool?"

    re, err := regexp.Compile(`[^\w]`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    str1 = re.ReplaceAllString(str1, " ")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(str1))
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(strings.ToLower(scanner.Text()))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See [strings.EqualFold](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#EqualFold).

Here is an [example](https://go.dev/play/p/lLDOopmXcRA).